# modify css of element not yet in dom based on matchmedia event

Tags: jquery, css, events, media-queries

I got this problem. I have a page with pictures. If I click on one an overlay is shown and an element is inserted in the overlay. I have this function that works on the same element on the element own page (not in the overlay). I can't get it to work on the inserted element instead.

```
//checks "input" visibility on screen width change
$(document).ready(function () {

    let comment_section = $('#single_p_inpt');

    // media query event handler
    if (matchMedia) {
        const mq_small = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)");
        mq_small.addListener(WidthChange_small);
        WidthChange_small(mq_small);
    }

// media query change
    function WidthChange_small(mq_small) {
        if (mq_small.matches) {

            if (comment_section.css('display') === 'flex') {

                comment_section.css('display', 'none');
            }

        }else{

            if (comment_section.css('display') === 'none') {

                comment_section.css('display', 'flex');

            }

        }
    }

});
```

The `#single_p_inpt` should be shown or hidden based on mediamatch. However since I don't have it on the dom how can I manipulate it's css after it's inserted in the dom?

Comment: Could you call your callback/listener after the insert event?

Comment: man, yes you were right. I didn't think about it. I made a function out of the code and called it after opening the overlay